# [unixODBC][FreeTDS][SQL Server]Unable to connect to data source

Tags: sql-server, debian, freetds, unixodbc

Im using Debian machine and I was trying to connect to remote sql server, but encounter the error when I try to connect via isql:

```
root@debian:~/installtest# isql -v SQLServer-Conn
[S1000][unixODBC][FreeTDS][SQL Server]Unable to connect to data source
[37000][unixODBC][FreeTDS][SQL Server]Login failed for user ''.
[ISQL]ERROR: Could not SQLConnect
```

Here is my odbc.ini

```
[SQLServer-Conn]
Description=MS SQL connection to remote db
Driver=FreeTDS
Server=10.xx.xx.xx
Port=49xxx
User=username
Password=password
Database=remotedb
Trace=No
```

Here is my odbcinst.ini

```
[FreeTDS]
Description = ODBC for SQL Srv
Driver      = /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/odbc/libtdsodbc.so
Setup       = /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/odbc/libtdsS.so
UsageCount  = 1
```

The db was fine as I was able to connect using this same machine via tsql command. So i'm not sure if im missing something on the .ini files
Thanks for the help

Comment: Were you able to get this to work? If so, can you please update your question with the exact odbc.ini and odbcinst.ini and freetds.conf files you used? As well as the exact connection string? That would be fabulous!

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass `isql` a username and password in addition to your DSN.

```
isql -v SQLServer-Conn username password
```

Give that a try - good luck!